# countability of maximums in nowhere differentiable but everywhere continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis

I am given a function 
$$
g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac 1 {2^n}h(2^n x)
$$
where $h(x)  =|x|$ on $[-1, 1]$ and $h$ is periodic. For $c\in D\subseteq [0,2], g(c) \ge g(x)$ for all $x$. Is $D$ countable?\

If I am not wrong, $c=2/3 \in D$ is one such point and it exhibits fractal like nature symmetric about center. Below is graph I plotted. In each iteration, I seem to get copy of max point on the other half. Is $D$ countable?

My guess is it's not countable since each latter half part or former half part might correspond to $0$ or $1$ like in Cantor set. Can anyone confirm?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theorem 3.1 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.1691.pdf) proves that the maximum value is indeed $2/3$ and that the level set of $2/3$ is uncountable.